# IBM Liberty Runtime Server.xml File Error

Tags: eclipse, open-liberty, server.xml

I am getting errors as follows in the Liberty Runtime server.xml in Eclipse, I could not solve it.

Multiple annotations found at this line:

1. No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema).
2. Referenced file contains errors (file:/C:/Users/lenovo/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/com.ibm.ws.st.core/Liberty Runtime/server.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details.

I used versions below

- Eclipse version: 2022-03
- IBM liberty Developer Tools 22.2
- IBM Liberty server runtime environment-22.0.0.11
- Windows 10

I unistalled eclipse, IBM Liberty Developer tools and IBM liberty server runtime environment and installed again eclipse and IBM Liberty Developer tools and IBM liberty server runtime environment (same versions) but problem still continues.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Expand the "XML Problem" in the Markers view you show and tell us what it says there.

Comment: Are you using an older version on purpose? The current release of Eclipse is 2022-12.

Comment: The marketplace entry only declares support for the 2022-03 release: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-liberty-developer-tools